# Как из кода открыть в визуальном редакторе файл

Tags: битрикс

Понадобилось по нажатию кнопки открыть произвольный файл в визуальном редакторе. Рылся в документации, нигде не нашел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Методами тыка и реверсинжинеринга выяснил:

```
   function Edit()
   {
       (new BX.CEditorDialog({'content_url':'/bitrix/admin/public_file_edit.php?lang=ru&path=%2Fsubdir%2Fkabinet%2Fcurrent.php&site=s1&back_url=%2Fsubdir%2Fkabinet%2F&templateID=gos_modern_green_s2&siteTemplateId=gos_modern_green_s2','width':'947','height':'593','min_width':'780','min_height':'400'})).Show();BX.removeClass(this.parentNode.parentNode, 'bx-panel-button-icon-active');
   }
```

Но в моем случае от неизвестных шаманств - штука зависала, так что со строкой `content_url` можно не хило помучится.